# functions for matrices / cluster analysis

Tags: r, function, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean-distance

I have the following problem. Maybe you can help me!

I have 60 matrices (60 trials). Each of those matrices is 16*1000 fileds big (16 angles and 1000 timestamps). The 16 angels are bodyangels.

Now I want to calculate the euclicid distance for each of the combinations (1770). So I would get 1770 matrices which are are 16*1000 fileds big.
The list for every combinations I would get through this formula:

```
>comb <- combinations(n=60, r=2, v=n, set=TRUE, repeats.allowed=FALSE)
```

The formula which I want to apply to each of these combinations is:

```
> dab <- sqrt(sum((a-b)^2)) # a and b are two matrices
```

I tried to create a function, which is fortunately only for single values, but not for whole matrices.:

```
>dist.fun <- function(x,y)
>{
>z <- sqrt(sum((x)-(y))^2)
>    return(z)
>}
```

Out of those distances I want to create an euclidic distance matrix to do a cluster analysis.

```
>plot(hclust((as.dist(m)),method="ward.D2")) # m is the euclidic disdance matrix
```

I hope, anyone can help me with this problem. The data is biomechanical data from gymnasts, which I want to investigate in terms of variant and invariant components and prototypes.